# How to automate switching Sensors/Location in Chrome DevTools for automated tests?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

**Context**

I would like to write automated tests using Selenium. My page should work correctly according the user's location. I want to assert different results depending on the user's location.

I would like to use Chrome DevTools's Sensors/Location facility to simulate different locations.

**Question**

How can I automate switch from one location setting to another according the test use case? (I am using Selenium Chrome driver from a C# code, but hopefully this should not matter)

[image]

Comment: You can set the latitude and longitude by using https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/DevTools/AutoGenerated/Emulation/SetGeolocationOverrideCommand.cs . You may not be able to find any method which take parameter as Location: San Francisco. When changing the Emulation.setGeolocationOverride add some wait of 20-30 seconds . In Java `' DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();devTools.createSession();devTools.send(Emulation.setGeolocationOverride(Optional.of(35.689487), Optional.of(139.691706), Optional.of(100))); `'

Comment: Many thanks, why not post it as answer so people can upvote

Comment: Added details in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the latitude and longitude `Emulation.setGeolocationOverride` from the Chrome dev tools can be used .

For C# Selenium binding refer [SetGeolocationOverrideCommand.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/DevTools/AutoGenerated/Emulation/SetGeolocationOverrideCommand.cs)

From my experience you may need to add some wait after calling Emulation.setGeolocationOverride . As it does not reflect immediately.

In Java Sample Code :

```
DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();
devTools.send(Emulation.setGeolocationOverride(Optional.of(35.689487), Optional.of(139.691706), Optional.of(100)))
```

In Selenium/Chromedriver Logs It will be visible something like :

```
Jun 23, 2020 4:47:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection send
INFO: {
  "id": 7,
  "method": "Emulation.setGeolocationOverride",
  "params": {
    "latitude": 35.689487,
    "longitude": 139.691706,
    "accuracy": 100
  },
  "sessionId": "SDSFDF3243423434DFDFD"
}
```

In Java if you are using maven add below dependency in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-5</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Note:**
Geolocation permission can be given to site using [Browser.grantPermissions](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#method-grantPermissions)

```
Browser.grantPermissions EXPERIMENTAL #
Grant specific permissions to the given origin and reject all others.
PARAMETERS
permissions
array[ PermissionType ]
origin
string
Origin the permission applies to, all origins if not specified.
```